# Why does the react hooks checkbox give an incorrect value?

Tags: checkbox, react-hooks, use-state

This checkbox is consistent in displaying the wrong value of 'checked'

```
 <input type='checkbox'
 name='isCheckeD' 
 id='isChecked'
 checked={formData.isCheckeD}
 onChange={handleChecked}
 />
```

the function is

```
function handleChecked(e) {
    const {name, checked} = e.target 
    formDataSet( cB => {
            return {...cB, [name]: checked}
        }) 
    console.log(formData.isChecked)

}
```

and the state is:

```
const [formData, formDataSet] = useState(
    {
     isCheckeD: false    
    }
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you seeing any incorrect value?

Comment: when the box is checked, console log gives 'false', and vice versa...

Comment: What console log are you referring to? Where are you logging any values? Have you included all relevant code you are working with in your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry, I have now added the console log to the original post.